# Counting unique values in a VBA array with user defined functions

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, array

I have a VBA function that goes through a few user supplied ranges based on user supplied conditions and adds items to an array. For its designed use cases it will almost surely add duplicates. At the end, I am interested in only the number of unique items in the array I've built.

I am trying to call this function:

```
Function GetUniqueCount(aFirstArray As Variant)

Dim arr As New Collection, a
Dim i As Long

On Error Resume Next

For Each a In aFirstArray
    arr.Add a, Str(a)
Next

GetUniqueCount = arr.Count

End Function
```

Like so:

```
Function Stuff(parameters)

Dim myArray() as Variant

...do things to populate myArray, finally

Stuff = GetUniqueCount(myArray)
```

The function GetUniqueCount is a very lightly modified tweak of the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017852/vba-get-unique-values-from-array) on a similar question.

When I do this, Stuff always ends up returning 1 even when it seems apparent that it should not. I tested Stuff up to this point and it is accurately producing the number of expected elements, I'm just doing something wrong when I try and count the number of those elements that are unique. Any help would be appreciated, as I am still getting the hang of VBA arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made several small changes to the *UDF()*..............study the differences:

```
Function GetUniqueCount(aFirstArray()) As Long
    Dim arr As Collection
    Set arr = New Collection

    On Error Resume Next
        For Each a In aFirstArray
            arr.Add a, CStr(a)
        Next
    On Error GoTo 0
    GetUniqueCount = arr.Count
End Function

Sub MAIN()
    Dim inpt()
    inpt = Array("alpha", "alpha", "beta", "beta", "gamma")
    MsgBox GetUniqueCount(inpt)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I refactored my design to be a little bit simpler and also incorporated what you offered here, leading to the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

'To check a range in a specific column, here is No. 8 (H colomn), which starts in row number 11, try the following code. (change the column and starting row to suit your need)

```
Sub Find_unique()
Dim Y As Integer, Z As Integer, cont As Integer, _
Vlue As String, lop1 As Integer, lop2 As Integer, duplct As Integer
        lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        lop1 = 11
        lop2 = 12   'Add 1 to the lop1 value
        If Len(Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(11, 8))) > 0 Then
        GoTo Act
        ElseIf (Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(11, 8))) = 0 Then
        GoTo Finish
        End If
Act:
       Y = lop1
        Vlue = ActiveSheet.Cells(Y, 8)
        cont = cont + 1
        For Z = lop2 To lastrow
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(Z, 8) = Vlue Then
        duplct = duplct + 1
        End If
        Next Z
        lop1 = lop1 + 1
        If Y = lastrow Then
        GoTo Don
        Else
        lop2 = lop2 + 1
        GoTo Act
        End If
Don:
        MsgBox "The total record is: " & cont _
        & vbCrLf & duplct & " of them are duplicated" _
        & vbCrLf & "unique counts: " & (cont - duplct)
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your code will be more readable if you indent properly.